# pyglet is there an easy way to draw empty rectangle

Tags: python, function, primitive, pyglet

I am looking for a way to draw border around areas using primitives like box or rectangle but cant find a implemented function on pyglet.

```
rectangle = shapes.Rectangle(box_position[0], box_position[1], box_position[2], box_position[3], batch=batch)
rectangle = shapes.BorderedRectangle(box_position[0], box_position[1], box_position[2], box_position[3], border_color=(255, 22, 20), batch=batch)
```

Comment: Same goes for `pygame`; you'll just have to draw two rects.